# XPath recursive "parent"-selection in a flat structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-3.0

The following XML is given:

```
<root>
  <element>
    <id>1</id>
  </element>
  <element>
    <id>2</id>
    <parentId>1</parentId>
  </element>
  <element>
    <id>3</id>
    <parentId>2</parentId>
  </element>
  <element>
    <id>4</id>
    <parentId>3</parentId>
  </element>
  <element>
    <id>5</id>
    <parentId>2</parentId>
  </element>
  <element>
    <id>6</id>
    <parentId>5</parentId>
  </element>
</root>
```

Now, I want to select all "parent"-nodes for e.g. element 3. Let's say, the desired output for element 3 should be:

- element 1
- element 2

The desired output for element 2 should be:

- element 1

And the desired output for element 6 should be

- element 5
- element 2
- element 1

Is this even possible to achieve with XPath? If yes, how could you do it?

Comment: How/where would you input the starting element?

Comment: With a variable in XSLT. Somehow like this: /root/element[magic = $startElement]

Comment: Actually in such "hierarchy" there may be more than one starting element. Algorithms and XSLT implementation exist that don't need to be provided with any "starting element" -- they find all possible "starting elements" and place them at the start of the sorted sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this even possible to achieve with XPath? If yes, how could you do
>   it?

**I. General XSLT 1.0 solution**

As expressed in a comment by the OA:

> "The goal is to produce parent-elements before their children."

This is also known as "***[topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)***"

And here is my XSLT 1.0 topological sort implementation, dated 2001:

"***[The Solution -- Re: how to rearrange nodes based on a dependency graph?](https://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200112/msg00972.html)***"

And here is another variation of this XSLT topological sorting "that keeps the cliques together" (stable topological sort) https://www.biglist.com/lists/lists.mulberrytech.com/xsl-list/archives/200112/msg01009.html

As for getting with **pure XPath** the sequence of IDs of the implied-hierarchy-ancestors for a given element, below is a solution using XPath 3.0 or later.

---

**II. Pure XPath 3 solution**

This XPath 3.0 expression defines an inline (XPath 3.0) function that calculates the ancestor-path of an element, passed as outside parameter $*pCurrent*:

```
   let $pCurrent := current(),
       $ancestor-path-inner := function($el as element(), $self as function(*)) as xs:string*
       {
           let $parent := $el/../element[id eq $el/parentId]
              return
               if(not(empty($parent))) then $self($parent, $self)
                 else ()
           ,
            $el/parentId
       },
       $ancestor-path := function($el as element()) as xs:string*
       { $ancestor-path-inner($el, $ancestor-path-inner)}
    return
      string-join($ancestor-path($pCurrent), '-')
```

**XSLT 3.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="element">
      <element id="{id}" ancestor-path-ids=
       "{let $pCurrent := current(),
             $ancestor-path-inner := function($el as element(), 
                                              $self as function(*)) as xs:string*
            {
              let $parent := $el/../element[id eq $el/parentId]
               return
                 if(not(empty($parent))) then $self($parent, $self)
                   else ()
                 ,
                 $el/parentId
            },
            $ancestor-path := function($el as element()) as xs:string*
             { $ancestor-path-inner($el, $ancestor-path-inner)}
       return
        string-join($ancestor-path($pCurrent), '-')}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <element>
        <id>1</id>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>2</id>
        <parentId>1</parentId>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>3</id>
        <parentId>2</parentId>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>4</id>
        <parentId>3</parentId>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>5</id>
        <parentId>2</parentId>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>6</id>
        <parentId>5</parentId>
    </element>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<element id="1" ancestor-path-ids=""/>
<element id="2" ancestor-path-ids="1"/>
<element id="3" ancestor-path-ids="1-2"/>
<element id="4" ancestor-path-ids="1-2-3"/>
<element id="5" ancestor-path-ids="1-2"/>
<element id="6" ancestor-path-ids="1-2-5"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like XPath 3 offers a solution! 

Comment: Yes, @moritz.vieli, XPath 3.0 is probably Turing-complete. For more information and demonstration on programming with XPath 3 read this:  https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/html/Novatchev01/BalisageVol10-Novatchev01.html  and watch this presentation (zipped PPT slides): https://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/author-pkg/Novatchev01/BalisageVol10-Novatchev01.html . Also this Pluralsight Course covers XPath 3.0:  https://www.pluralsight.com/library/courses/xpath-3-0-whats-new/table-of-contents

Comment: Great XPath 3.0 example.

Comment: @Alejandro Your appreciation is valuable for me. For more complete introduction into "Programming with XPath 3", click on the links in my comment above -- I recommend the slides in particular. Hope you will like this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="start-id"/>

<xsl:key name="elem" match="element" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem', $start-id)"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <element id="{id}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem', parentId)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applying this to your XML input with a `start-id` parameter value of `6`, will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <element id="6"/>
  <element id="5"/>
  <element id="2"/>
  <element id="1"/>
</root>
```

To exclude the starting node and list only its ancestors, you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="start-id" select="6"/>

<xsl:key name="elem" match="element" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem', key('elem', $start-id)/parentId)"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <element id="{id}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem', parentId)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example! I need it in a for-each as sort expression. The goal is to produce parent-elements before their children. Maybe I can also rewrite the for-each to apply-templates, but it's rather complicate and I'd need to check it.

Comment: If you want to reverse the order, then simply move the `<element id="{id}"/>` instruction **after** `the <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elem', parentId)"/>` instruction. You don't need to use `xsl:for-each`, and you cannot use `xsl:for-each` with this type of input. You need to proceed recursively from child to parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact, I have two lists. One with the elements and one with the element-relations. I need to output all elements, regardless of the relations. The relations only specify the order (sometimes there's no relation for an element). Is this still possible with apply-templates somehow? I'll check it anyway, but I think it will get very complicated.

Comment: Solved it with a recursive XSLT-function now. So the final answer would be, that this requirement cannot be achieved with XPath only, I suppose.

Comment: Probably not.  ---

Comment: @moritz.vieli Actually, the final answe **is** that there is a pure XPath solution -- enjoy!